# Burnination is the [next] step

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

<s>32</s> 7 questions labeled [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next), none of them are related. Some refer to jQuery iterators, some refer to SQL index enumeration, some refer to reading files... it's a mess. There is a wiki, but it's one sentence and it's as vague as the tag's content.

**Update:** the tag excerpt now contains this text:

> Do NOT use this tag for Next.js, use [next.js] instead. For questions related to Iterator, use [iterator]. For questions related to JQuery selectors, use [jquery-selectors]. For questions related to pagination, use [pagination]

*The tag now (9 years after this question) mostly contains questions that is about [next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js), but by mistake use this [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next) that can be associated to many different things, as noted in the first paragraph.*

Interestingly (or not), there is no [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/previous).

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. It may refer to iterators, next line of text, next element of HTML or XML, the next item in an array, the Basic NEXT statement, ...
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No. The concept described by the tag wiki is not `next`, it is `iterator`.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No

Comment: Quite a few should instead use [tag:iterator]

Comment: Sounds like a cleanup is in order before burnination is considered.

Comment: Many of the questions tagged both [javascript] and [next] probably meant to use [next.js] instead of [next], that is around 200+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next+javascript

Comment: There are still 140 questions with this tag, I'm currently editing all of them by myself. Can we maybe delete this tag after it's cleaned up?

Comment: @Gugu72 Once there are no questions associated with the tag, it will be automatically deleted by the nightly roomba process.

Comment: Alright, we're down to 0 now, but the challenge is now to keep it at zero until roomba does it's job. It seems that it was already down to zero until about 40 minutes ago, but then the next question was created with this tag (instead of [next.js]), which I fixed now. As it seems to be so popular, we really have to watch it.

Comment: I have ended this by merging the tag into [next.js] (there was one question at the time, because people seem really determined to use the tag).

Comment: Am I reading this right?  Did it actually take *nine years* to burninate this tag?

Comment: I'm like a whole different person now than when I opened this. Not really, but yeah 9 years is a long time!